# cassandra cqlsh <composed_ttl> error

Tags: cassandra, cql, ttl

I´m learning Cassandra CQL using CQL 3.1 documentation manual on mac with cassandra installed from homebrew (cqlsh 4.0.0 | Cassandra 2.0.0 | CQL spec 3.1.0 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0). From cqlsh, when I enter [collections map example number 7](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html#task_ds_cvq_kcl_zj):

```
UPDATE users USING TTL <computed_ttl> SET todo['2012-10-1'] = 'find water' WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

I´m getting this error:

Bad Request: line 1:22 no viable alternative at input '<'

So, docs are wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `<computed_ttl>` with an actual TTL e.g.

```
UPDATE users USING TTL 100 SET todo['2012-10-1'] = 'find water' WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

which would cause the value to expire after 100 seconds.